# Rest services design

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Rest service for update client - for example 
`PUT - /client/{id}`
this rest service is validate received client and if something wrong will throw a Businesses exception. So now I have to have a possibility to validate client without persist to know what kind of fields are wrong. Please who can help me to design REST with best practise, because I use the same url 
`PUT - /client/{id}?validOnly=true` with query param validOnly.

Thanks

Comment: What type of validation are you doing? Are you just testing data consistency from your request? Or data consistency against other data?

Comment: no - I use drools validation - it's not a simple logic

Comment: I'm still wondering why soo many people call these RPC-style services exposed via HTTP `REST`. REST is an architectural style in distributed systems which you would apply if you need decoupling of client from servers, similar to the browser which is independant from the plethora of web servers and their arbitrary content. This design though relies heavily on content-negotiation and the specification of media-types and their support by utilizing libraries that implement these specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the input a Vaalidator class inside your rest service app. Why you need client validation for that. If at all you need to validate the input at client. What kind of validation you want.

Comment: I use drools validation - it's not a simple logic! This service asked my customer!

Comment: Please clarify the flow and what validation you are doing in details. May be I can help